# switch statement over performing with char variable in c++

Tags: c++, string, input, char, switch-statement

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun() {
   while(1) {
      char choice;
      cout<<"(D)isplay, (E)xit"<<endl;
start:
      cout<<">> ";
      cin>>choice;
      switch(choice) {
         case 'd':
         case 'D':
            cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
            break;
         case 'e':
         case 'E':
            return;
         default:
            cout<<"INVALID!"<<endl;
            goto start;
      }
   }
}
int main() {
   system("clear");
   fun();

   return 0;
}
```

This is  a simple c++ program.
I am faciing following problem:

```
(D)isplay, (E)xit
>> mnop
INVALID!                                                  
>> INVALID!                                               
>> INVALID!
>> INVALID!
>>
```

The symbol '>>' prompt user to enter a character and with that it give apppropriate result but if entered a string it behaves something like this. I want to know why this happens and how to stop it :)

Comment: Aside: you don't need `goto start`, you are within a while loop

Comment: curiosity: Why did you tag `string` ? If you had used a `string` in your code your current issue would not be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does what you told it to but not more: `cin>>choice;` reads a single character. When the user types more than a single character then the other characters are left in the stream and will be read by the next call.

If you want to handle input of more than a single character properly then you need to extract more than single character from the stream. For example:

```
 while (true) {
     std::string input;
     std::cin >> input;
     if (input.size() > 1 || input.size() == 0) {
         std::cout << "enter only a single character\n";
     } else {
         choice = input[0];
         break;
     }
}
```

Alternatively you could check if there are more characters left in the stream after reading one and/or simply discard them (via `ignore`).

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `cin.clear()` after getting your value, and possibly also `cin.ignore(INT_MAX)`. This will clear the buffer for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is happening ?

Comment: What happens is that you ask for a single char, and so what `std::cin` does is that it takes in your input and whatever is left is stored in a buffer. If `std::cin` gets called again it will simply continue reading from the buffer until it's empty. This is why your loop runs multiple times. Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

cin >> choice , you are reading only one char. Remaining chars remain in buffer and read when you again call cin >> choice. Try string asdf then you will see output.

You can flush std in or simply read all remaining chars using cin.read();

basically clear input buffer by reading all chars.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a character input from the user. Char means only one character so if you enter a string like "mnop", there are four characters in that. Each is considered as a separate input so you get "INVALID!" four times.

A solution can be to take a string input and check the length of that input first. If it is greater than 1 then ignore it else check whether if its 'D' or 'E'.

You can also use getch() function. It restricts the user to enter only one character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
char ch = getch();
```

Comment: `conio.h` is not a standard C++ header.

Comment: Well, you can also use getchar() in place of getch().